# Is it possible to type check using `is` without knowing the generic used?

Tags: c#, generics, types

Is it possible to check if a variable is of a specific type that uses a generic, without knowing what that generic is? For example, the code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        if (list is List<object>)
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Failure");
    }
}
```

outputs `failure` even though `string` inherits from `object`. How can I make this program recognise that `list` is of type `List<T>` without knowing what `T` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a help of [GetGenericTypeDefinition()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition?view=net-7.0) method to *strip* generic `T` from `List<T>` and have `List<>` type (note abscence of `T` and empty `<>`) to compare with:

```
if (list.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
  Console.WriteLine("Success");
else
  Console.WriteLine("Failure");
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zgSZXh)

Comment: Note that unlike the normal "is" operator, this *won't* show Success if you're using a subclass of List, e.g. `class StringList : List<string>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can test for the non-generic interface `IList`:

```cs
if (list is IList)
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Failure");
```

Note that this also succeds for arrays. Therefore test with (using pattern matching):

```cs
if (list is IList{ IsReadOnly: false }) ...
```

You can assign the result to a new variable at the same time:

```cs
if (maybeList is IList{ IsReadOnly: false } list) ...
```